# Can use v-for with :value

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I don't understand why i can't replace the :value=MYVALUE by :value={{ item.level }}.
Can someone explain me

```
 <v-progress-circular v-for="item in Webs" :key="item.name"
                :rotate="-90"
                :size="100"
                :width="15"
                :value=70
                color="primary"
            >
                {{ item.name }}
            </v-progress-circular>
        <script>
      export default {
        name: 'Test',
        data() {
          return {
                Webs: [
                    {
                        logo: 'https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.blog-nouvelles-technologies.fr%2F2312%2Fhtml5-ou-html-la-question-se-pose%2F&psig=AOvVaw2SaUGiuxy1TtXH7KAHefnq&ust=1589414369428000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCIiV7ojEr-kCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAZ',
                        name: 'html',
                        level: 70,
                    }
                ],

            }
        }
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: It should be `:value="item.level"`, similar to what you've got for the `key`. You don't use `{{ ... }}` with `v-bind`, they're for outputting text content, not setting attributes.

Answer (score 2):

You can certaintly use any dynamic value with `:value` attribute (either bind it with `v-model` specifier or use it as `:value`)

correct version would be following:

```
<template>
    <v-progress-circular 
    v-for="item in Webs" 
    :key="item.name"
    :rotate="-90"
    :size="100"
    :width="15"
    :value="item.level"
    color="primary">

    {{ item.name }}
  </v-progress-circular>
</template>
<script>
      export default {
        name: 'Test',
        data() {
          return {
                Webs: [
                    {
                        logo: 'https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.blog-nouvelles-technologies.fr%2F2312%2Fhtml5-ou-html-la-question-se-pose%2F&psig=AOvVaw2SaUGiuxy1TtXH7KAHefnq&ust=1589414369428000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCIiV7ojEr-kCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAZ',
                        name: 'html',
                        level: 70,
                    }
                ],

            }
        }
      }
</script>
```

remember to quote `:value="item.level"`,

hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

:value="item.level" means v-bind:value="item.level", the value after 'v-bind:' is reactive and the value in mustaches is reactive too. If they exist together, Vue cannot response reactively。It is determined by the definition of Vue

Comment: Hi Emma, thanks for trying. But it's a simple syntax thing. Your explanation just isn't true.